# Como redireccionar de un navegador a otro

Tags: php, html5, css3, navegador-web

tengo una pregunta, se puede redireccionar a otro navegador desde un enlace en html? Al entrar al sitio web https://www.xbox.com te aparece despues de unos segundos, un header arriba del menu, que dice que si quieres probar ese sitio web en el navegador Microsoft Edge, y yo quiero saber como redireccionar a cualquier otro navegador, no necesariamente a Microsoft Edge, espero su respuesta con ansias jeje, gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Respuesta rápida: No.
>
> En casos particulares -> sí
>
> En todos lados y todos los navegadores -> no
>
> **Es algo que depende del navegador, y del sistema operativo.**

En primer lugar, hablamos del [URI SCHEME](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme)

Es decir, existen diferentes protocolos que hacen diferentes acciones. Para ello, los sistemas operativos y los navegadores, han de tener claro qué deben utilizar para abrir ese protocolo.

Por otro lado, los navegadores comienzan a implementar la posibilidad de manejar protocolos "custom", que pueden redirigirte a aplicaciones web.

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Navigator/registerProtocolHandler/Web-based_protocol_handlers

El tema, que en Windows también puedes [registrar tus propios handlers](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa767914(v=vs.85)) que básicamente es lo que hacen ellos cuando instalas Windows

Luego, en el site de Xbox, sólo tienen que detectar si tu navegador no es Edge, y si tienes windows, poner a un link que tiene "Microsoft-Edge en la cabecera y con eso, te enviarán un link de descarga, o lo abrirán directamente.

Comment: Si se detectar el navegador y sistema operativo, pero no se enlazarlos

Comment: como? que no sabes cómo enlazar el q?

Comment: Los navegadores

Comment: Si lo hacen con Edge se puede hacer con los demas, yo pienso